# Favorable laws for graywater usage

Tags: greywater, law

I know that it is illegal to catch and use graywater in many US states.  What states and/or nations have favorable laws for graywater usage?

Comment: It's a bit of a broad and general question, and probably unanswerable in its current form, but I've provided one example of a regulatory regime where it is favourable, with links to all the regulatory detail

Comment: It is broad, and not amenable to one correct answer.  Even so - those of us fighting to change legislation in unfavorable areas could really benefit from having this info to point to.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that you were looking for some exemplary legislation to use as part of a campaign for change.  And I guess you may be interested in countries where a lot of buildings have greywater recycling - I don't know where to find statistics, but that might make a good question in its own right: you could look at where the highest greywayer recycling rates are, and then look at the regulatory regime there.

Comment: A fine idea!  I'll ask...

Answer (score 5):

The Building Regulations for England, and the national (largely voluntary) [Code for Sustainable Homes](https://www.gov.uk/government/policies/improving-the-energy-efficiency-of-buildings-and-using-planning-to-protect-the-environment/supporting-pages/code-for-sustainable-homes), cover [water efficiency and greywater recycling](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/the-water-efficiency-calculator-for-new-dwellings). The [calculation for legal compliance](http://www.thewatercalculator.org.uk/) includes the ability to achieve compliance by increasing your energy efficiency through greywater recycling, so it is **actively encouraged by the regulatory regime**.

[image]

The specific legal documents are the [Water Supply (Water Fittings) Regulations 1999](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1999/1148/contents/made) and the Building Regulations (parts [G](http://www.planningportal.gov.uk/buildingregulations/approveddocuments/partg/) & [H](http://www.planningportal.gov.uk/buildingregulations/approveddocuments/parth/)). The former [requires](http://www.rainwindsun.com/faqs/grey-water.html):

> backflow protection of any public mains supply “back up” connection. They also place an obligation on installers not to allow cross-connection of mains-fed pipework with pipes carrying recycled water, and to clearly mark the pipes to distinguish recycled water from mains derived water

Answer (score 5):

Washington State recently implemented a new set of rules allowing greywater. Details: http://www.doh.wa.gov/CommunityandEnvironment/WastewaterManagement/GreywaterReuse.aspx

In my experience, greywater legislation is typically focused on **plumbing and building codes**, e.g. "Can I plumb my shower to drain in to the garden?" and not behavior, e.g. "can I take a shower in the garden".

A lot of **behaviors** are not so much legal or illegal, as outside of the purview of law.